# Plantuml connection alignment and layout problem

Tags: layout, label, connection, plantuml

Working around on the deployment diagram for several hours, but still can't figure out how to align and format the lines and the labels of lines neatly. The following URL is a simple example of the [deployment diagram](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/dT2n3W8n20RWkJm5Bt33TNGmvtCOXxCbPnCAbnPDZF7TxQBfqCc5vOSlm59jBNRF38M2hR8nOT2ygv3O2L-0YF26BXMgHh4bhfku9Oupdi6vgfdmGUNP5LRPcYhMJ8nKGqcx9HLmbv7j1xZ_5--EcQRZT_i3ydebndcS-r-3XuKajlzy0000)

Questions

1. The connection is tidier to point to the center of the both rectangles (as shown in red lines) other than the side and the edge of the rectangle, is there anyway to force the pointer to point to the center?
   [image]
2. Can I align the label in parallel with the lines, plantUML align the label horizontally regardless of how the line draws, but it is tidier to let the label alongside with how the line is draw, is there any way / tricks can be used here to achieve?
   [image]

Appreciate for any help, thank you

Comment: Please include the plantuml source of your examples.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator  Sorry for the wrong link, I have updated the plantuml source, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I used some `port`s to force the links to the top of the components, but it's probably not possible to get them perfectly in the center.
2. As far as I know, it's not possible to have text labels follow the lines.

```
@startuml

skinparam componentstyle rectangle

component componentA {
}

together {
component "\nNested" as nested {
    port " " as p1
    component child1 [
        some very very very
        long content description
    ]
}

component "\nNested 2" as nested2 {
    port " " as p2
    component child2 [
        some very very very
        long content description
    ]
}

}

componentA --> p1 : label 1
componentA --> p2 : label 2

@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this hack at least align the lines "closer" to center, but the label thing... is a shame as it is quite comment aligning the label parallel to the lines, thank you anyway!